# python file copying

Tags: python, windows, performance, comparison

Is there any difference in speed of copying files from one location to another betwen python or delphi or c++ ? 
I guess that all 3 laguages uses same or similar win api calls and that there is not much performance difference.

Comment: Please (1) Run each alternative, (2) Collect timing data and (3) post your timing results so we can comment on them.  We're not going to run the timings for you.  But you can run them and ask **specific** questions about what you saw.

Answer (score 1):

Pythons `shutil` module does *not* use the Windows API, but instead uses an open/read/write loop. This may or may not be slower than using `CopyFile(Ex)`. Please measure it, everything else is just guessing.